# I am trying to map an image so it will link certain sections to a different page I need another set of eyes

Tags: html

I can't get links onto certain parts of the image I am using. Even though I looked over it numerous times. Can someone else have a look to see if my code is off.

```html
    <img id="gtxports" alt="GTX Titan Black Ports" 
    src="https://i.ibb.co/h9y4V3S/gtxtitanports.jpg" usemap="gtxpports">

    <map name="gtxpports" id="gtxPortsMap">
    <area alt="Dual DVI D" title="Dual DVI D" href="dualdviD.html" 
    shape="rect" coords="1045, 453, 1653, 633" />
    <area alt="Dual DVI I" title="Dual DVI I" href="dualdvii.html" 
    shape="rect" coords="1045, 773, 1653, 969" />
    <area alt="HDMI Port" title="HDMI Port" href="hdmi.html" shape="rect" 
    coords="577, 829, 861, 965" />
    <area alt="DisplayPort" title="DisplayPort" href="displayport.html" 
    shape="rect" coords="193, 825, 525, 969" />
    </map>
```

Comment: Gladly, perhaps you should try and post the code here? :)

Comment: my bad I fixed it

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, I tested this out and there are 4 clickable areas on the components that seem to be working fine.  What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I am unable to click the four clickable areas, I have another page unrelated to this one where it worked but it just seems to not want to for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where and how you are referring to the html link as I believe it's on your local machine. Rewriting the existing code works fine for me, refer below:

```html
    <img id="gtxports" alt="GTX Titan Black Ports" 
    src="https://i.ibb.co/h9y4V3S/gtxtitanports.jpg" usemap="gtxpports">
    
    <map name="gtxpports" id="gtxPortsMap">
        <area href="https://google.com" alt="Dual DVI D" title="Dual DVI D" target="_blank" shape="rect" coords="1045, 453, 1653, 633" />
        <area href="https://google.com" alt="Dual DVI I" title="Dual DVI I" target="_blank" shape="rect" coords="1045, 773, 1653, 969" />
        <area href="https://google.com" alt="HDMI Port" title="HDMI Port" target="_blank" shape="rect" coords="577, 829, 861, 965" />
        <area href="https://google.com" alt="DisplayPort" title="DisplayPort" target="_blank" shape="rect" coords="193, 825, 525, 969" />
    </map>
```

You can test this on real-time via https://htmledit.squarefree.com/ or any other real-time html viewer. Replace google.com with your link to see if it works, if it dosesn't then possibly some problem with the destination of the html pages you are referring to.

Comment: It does seem that there is a problem connecting the html pages I am referring to although when I try to even link it to google it still does not work. So I am unsure of what the issue is.

Comment: The above code works fine at my end, so no issue with the code. Are you trying this on your machine or you have hosted it somewhere?

Comment: I am trying this on my machine.

Comment: Class ends in a minute so I must go now, I will try to fix this tomorrow, thank you for your help though. Much appreciated. :)